# no connection to Nginx docker container on port 80 and 443

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, raspberry-pi

please help me with the following problem. I try to setup a Wordpress site within a Nginx docker container on a Raspberry pi. I can establish a connection to the container without any problems, if I set port in the docker-compose.xml from 80 to 8300. If I leave port as 80, I cannot connect to the container.

edit:
Changing the port to "8300" is only a workaround. My aim is to have it listening and working on port "80".

I 'm using the docker-compose.yml file from [this Github](https://github.com/mjstealey/wordpress-nginx-docker)

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.6'
 services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:${WORDPRESS_VERSION:-php7.3-fpm}
    container_name: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./config/php.conf.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/conf.ini
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME:-wordpress}
      - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX:-wp_}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST:-mysql}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${WORDPRESS_DB_USER:-root}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:-password}
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always

  mysql:
    image: jsurf/rpi-mariadb
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-password}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER:-root}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-password}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE:-wordpress}
    restart: always

 

   nginx:
    image: nginx:${NGINX_VERSION:-latest}
    container_name: nginx-wp
    ports:
      - '80:80' -> if I change this to 8300:80 I can connect with http://192.168.178.33:8300
      - '443:443' 
#    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ${NGINX_CONF_DIR:-./nginx}:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${NGINX_LOG_DIR:-./logs/nginx}:/var/log/nginx
      - ${WORDPRESS_DATA_DIR:-./wordpress}:/var/www/html
      - ${SSL_CERTS_DIR:-./certs}:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ${SSL_CERTS_DATA_DIR:-./certs-data}:/data/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
 - wordpress
    restart: always

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

default.conf

```
        server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.178.33;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;
    
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
    
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }
```

excerpt from 'net stat -lnp'

```
    dennis@ras-test:~/wordpress-nginx-docker/nginx $ sudo netstat -lnp
    [sudo] password for dennis: 
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      604/sshd            
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      649/mysqld          
    tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      19695/proftpd: (acc 
    tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      604/sshd            
    tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      20810/docker-proxy  
    tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      20824/docker-proxy  
    tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      20474/docker-proxy  
    udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           563/dhcpcd          
    udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46285           0.0.0.0:*                           366/avahi-daemon: r 
    udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           366/avahi-daemon: r 
    udp6       0      0 :::44824                :::*                                366/avahi-daemon: r 
    udp6       0      0 :::546                  :::*                                563/dhcpcd          
    udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                366/avahi-daemon: r 
    raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           563/dhcpcd          
    Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
    Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10253    1/init               /run/systemd/private
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10259    1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     33872    4288/docker-contain  @/containerd-shim/moby/8851b28f3b62c3f34f4e952c47aa45264f9069551b8922e1c74914e7ccb64b32/shim.sock@
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     10277    1/init               /run/udev/control
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17722    567/dockerd          /run/docker/libnetwork/36e57c3fb20abc31554be32a4ac7d5967c015c2544b751c344f062771fa004ed.sock
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10313    1/init               /run/systemd/fsck.progress
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17006    696/docker-containe  /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd-debug.sock
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17008    696/docker-containe  /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     104003   20250/docker-contai  @/containerd-shim/moby/5555f8fa664229dc3703d3309ffb4f66e70ebe83e505fe509975b36708655651/shim.sock@
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22942    1811/systemd         /run/user/1001/systemd/private
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     34079    4544/docker-contain  @/containerd-shim/moby/d901c4fb9cf498e7d0f83e2ba9a2a769758ae7b96ee51de07cc9b8cde519a51d/shim.sock@
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22948    1811/systemd         /run/user/1001/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22951    1811/systemd         /run/user/1001/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22953    1811/systemd         /run/user/1001/gnupg/S.dirmngr
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22955    1811/systemd         /run/user/1001/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22957    1811/systemd         /run/user/1001/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12206    1/init               /var/run/docker.sock
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12210    1/init               /run/thd.socket
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12213    1/init               /run/avahi-daemon/socket
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12217    1/init               /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     105064   20500/docker-contai  @/containerd-shim/moby/07c722f4c931607304dcee0a690055ffa8b579c4b9e3b100283b7938646589ba/shim.sock@
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16326    567/dockerd          /var/run/docker/metrics.sock
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     107522   20831/docker-contai  @/containerd-shim/moby/d8b3e50547f42eb7f656e46cf8ab2dada0e83ae79940d26e8bbbfb0ae1f5138b/shim.sock@
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16850    649/mysqld           /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     102322   20469/docker-contai  @/containerd-shim/moby/ec1049189a85ab13c759095ce82e5172b3ecfde074fc387f3942e4508930413d/shim.sock@
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     26047    2969/docker-contain  @/containerd-shim/moby/52a275d3d83ad6dd8165e5a08b9b4b05bc10879aaba9a3e429d319d5f8adc186/shim.sock@
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12775    563/dhcpcd           /var/run/dhcpcd.sock
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12777    563/dhcpcd           /var/run/dhcpcd.unpriv.sock
```

this is the output of "docker-compose up"

```
dennis@ras-test:~/wordpress-nginx-docker $ docker-compose up
mysql is up-to-date
wordpress is up-to-date
wordpress-nginx-docker_adminer_1 is up-to-date
nginx-wp is up-to-date
Attaching to mysql, wordpress, wordpress-nginx-docker_adminer_1, nginx-wp
wordpress    | [11-Jul-2020 23:30:28] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
wordpress    | [11-Jul-2020 23:30:28] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:32:20 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:32:26 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:34:21 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:34:27 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:36:22 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:36:28 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:38:22 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:38:28 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:40:23 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:40:28 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:42:23 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:42:28 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:44:24 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:44:29 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:46:25 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:46:29 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:48:26 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:48:31 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:50:26 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:50:31 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:52:27 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:52:32 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:54:28 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:54:34 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:56:28 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:56:35 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:58:28 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  11/Jul/2020:23:58:36 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:00:28 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:00:36 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:02:28 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:02:38 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:04:29 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:04:38 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:06:31 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:06:39 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:08:31 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:08:40 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:10:31 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:10:41 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:12:32 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.0.38-MariaDB-0+deb8u1) starting as process 1 ...
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.
mysql        | 
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:12:42 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:14:35 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:14:45 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:16:38 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:16:45 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:18:39 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:18:46 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:20:40 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:20:46 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:22:41 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:22:47 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:24:41 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:24:48 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:26:42 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:26:49 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:28:43 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:28:50 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:30:44 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.42-84.2 started; log sequence number 2938085
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@089a56c71380' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql        | 200712  1:30:24 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql        | Version: '10.0.38-MariaDB-0+deb8u1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Raspbian)
nginx-wp     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx-wp     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx-wp     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx-wp     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx-wp     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: error: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
nginx-wp     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx-wp     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:30:51 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:32:44 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:32:51 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:34:44 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:34:52 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:36:45 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:36:53 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:38:46 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:38:54 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:40:47 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:40:55 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:42:48 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:42:55 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:44:49 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:44:55 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:46:49 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:46:57 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:48:50 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:48:57 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:50:51 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:00:50:58 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:06:52:35 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
adminer_1    | [Sat Jul 11 23:30:27 2020] PHP 7.4.8 Development Server (http://[::]:8080) started
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:06:52:43 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:09:57:18 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:09:57:25 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:09:59:18 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:09:59:25 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:10:01:19 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:10:01:28 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:10:03:19 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
wordpress    | 172.30.0.5 -  12/Jul/2020:10:03:31 +0000 "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 200
```

output of "docker ps"

```
dennis@ras-test:~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
d8b3e50547f4        nginx:latest               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   11 hours ago        Up 11 hours         0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   nginx-wp
ec1049189a85        wordpress:php7.3-fpm       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 hours ago        Up 11 hours         9000/tcp                                   wordpress
07c722f4c931        adminer                    "entrypoint.sh docke…"   11 hours ago        Up 11 hours         0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                     wordpress-nginx-docker_adminer_1
5555f8fa6642        jsurf/rpi-mariadb          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 hours ago        Up 11 hours         3306/tcp                                   mysql
d901c4fb9cf4        nginx                      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   14 hours ago        Up 14 hours         80/tcp                                     dennis_web_1
8851b28f3b62        wordpress:5-fpm            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 hours ago        Up 14 hours         9000/tcp                                   dennis_php_1
52a275d3d83a        jsurf/rpi-mariadb:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 hours ago        Up 14 hours         3306/tcp                                   dennis_db_1
```

output of "docker-compose ps"

```
    dennis@ras-test:~ $ docker-compose ps
               Name                          Command                State      Ports  
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    b4e18e9010c2_dennis_nginx_1   /init                            Exit 128           
    dennis_db_1                   docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up         3306/tcp
    dennis_php_1                  docker-entrypoint.sh php-fpm     Up         9000/tcp
    dennis_web_1                  /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up         80/tcp  
    dennis@ras-test:~ $
```

Thank you in advance
Please let me know if I should provide more information

Comment: I recommend providing more specific information on exactly what you changed to modify the port (i.e. which lines in which file(s)). Also, have you tried creating a [minimum, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Creating as simple a version of your code and container as possible that still generates the error will help people give the solution (and you may find the root cause in attempting to do so), also making it a better fit for the site.

Comment: You defined that port   `#       - "8300:80"`  did you build it again? and please post the sequence you used to build and run your services. `docker-compose ps` can show you the ports.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I in fact did not rebuild the image. I only chanced the port from "80:80" to "8300:80" in the docker-compose.yml and rerun it with "docker-compose up". I'm going to add the other information you've requested in my question.

Comment: I only changed port "80:80" to "8300":80" in the docker-compose.yml under Nginx service.